# Get MySQL data in PHP when its formatted as 1:2:3:4

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pull data to PHP to create a simple stats page, with most my databases the stats are split in separate columns so I am able to do this:

```
    <tbody>
        <?php
        mysqli_select_db($connect, $database);;

        $sql = "SELECT name,kills FROM global_stats ORDER BY kills DESC LIMIT 5";

        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

        $count = 1;

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            echo "<tr> <td>" . $count . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['kills'] .  "</td> </tr>";
            $count++;
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
```

Although with one of my databases the data is saved in a strange way, where the data for each stat is all in one table separated by: - is there a way I can get all the data in the 2nd area for example, and the username, and then sort just the second area and output just 5 results.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the function [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index). But you should have stored stats in separate columns and/or rows if you wanted to fetch individual stats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT 
  name,
  CONVERT( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(stats, ':', 2), ':', -1), INTEGER) as kills
FROM
  table
ORDER BY kills DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Will convert the second field and return the top 5 - I don't know where the name comes from because it's not in your screenshot so some more work may be required

It works by using substring index twice. The first use (inner one) means "count forwards to the second delimiter starting from the left and use it as the end point for the substring" and then the second use (the outer one) means "count backwards to the first delimiter and use it as the start point for the substring

Comment: Seam to get a MySQL error using this :/ 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONVERT( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(stats, ':', 2), ':', -1), INTEGER) as ' at line 3

The name table is just called player_name so I swapped that out.

``SELECT 
  player_name.
  CONVERT( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(stats, ':', 2), ':', -1), INTEGER) as kills
FROM
  stats
ORDER BY kills DESC
LIMIT 5``

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo of putting a period after player_name instead of a comma. Commas are used to separate one column from another